# Reverse Engineering Camtastic file to PCB in Altium

Tags: pcb-design, altium, reverse-engineering

I've followed the directions found [here](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/CAM+Editor+Reverse+Engineering+PCBs) but after the step where I extract the netlists, when I export to PCB it gives the following error.

```
Error reading the nets from CAMtastic ! (C:\Build\platform_edp\CAMTASTIC\Source Code\Dlls\CAMUtils\ExportCAMToPCB.pas, line 296) at 29C46048.
CAMTASTIC.DLL, Base Address: 29830000.

Exception Occurred In 
ExportToPCB
```

This is a single layer import.

Here is what I have setup:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After working with this for over a year I've found a couple ways of achieving this.

First, working with DXF files is superior. I usually can import those directly into the pcb editor. If I can't, I import them into the cam editor, then export them to another DXF file, then import them into the pcb editor.

If I only have Cam files, The one thing I missed was this

[image]

Within Tables > NC tools  I needed to specify a drill size. Often times that fixed my problem.

Comment: Good on you for following up